# Application of Schawarz lemma??

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, analyticity

Let $f$ be an analytic function defined on the unit disc $D=\{z:|z|<1$. If $|f(z)|\leq 1-|z|$ for all $z\in D$ then show that $f$ is a zero function on $D$.

We have $|f(z)|\leq 1-|z|$ for all $z$ which implies that $|f(z)|\leq 1$ for all $z$..

Let $a\in(0,1)$. $f$ is analytic on $\{z: |z|\leq a\}=D_a$. So, by cauchy integral formula, we have 
$$f(0)=\frac{1}{2\pi i}\int_{\partial D_a}\frac{f(w)}{w}dw.$$
Further, $$|f(0)|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi }\int_{\partial D_a}\frac{|f(w)|}{|w|}|dw|\leq\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1-|w|}{|w|}ad\theta=\frac{1}{2\pi}\frac{1-a}{a}a2\pi=1-a.$$
So, $|f(0)|\leq 1-a$ for all $a\in(0,1)$. So, $f(0)=0$.

So, $f(0)=0$ and $|f(z)|\leq 1-|z|$. So, by Schwarz lemma, $|f(z)|\leq |z|$ for all $z\in D$...

Then i see that $|f(z)|\leq |z|$ and $|f(z)|\leq 1-|z|$ implies $2|f(z)|\leq 1-|z|+|z|=1$ implies $|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{2}$

I thought i can repeat this and conclude that $|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{n}$ for all $n$ and then conclude that $f$ is zero but i am getting $|f(z)|\leq \frac{1}{2}$ only and no better bound.

I am not able to proceed...

Comment: I think that this is really easy to prove using the maximum principle. Why use Schwartz lemma?

Comment: @Guy : Is that so? How? Can you give me some hint?

Comment: Consider the function $M_f(r)=\max_{|z|=r}\left|f(z)\right|$ defined on $\left[0,1\right)$. If $f$ is analytic on $D$ (generally, without the assumption of this exercise) -- what can you say?

Comment: @Guy : I am sorry, i do not understand that quite..

Comment: Do you understand why $M_f(r)=\max_{|z|\leq r}\left|f(z)\right|$?

Comment: @Guy : YEs i do.. that is boundary maximum modulus princinpe

Comment: I will write hints in a separate answer

Answer (score 0):

Here are hints:

1. For a function $f$ analytic on the open disc $D$, define $$M_f(r)=\max_{|z|=r}\left|f(z)\right|$$for $r\in\left[0,1\right). $Prove that $$M_f(r)=\max_{|z|\leq r}\left|f(z)\right|$$
2. Conclude that $M_f(r)$ is monotonically increasing on $\left[0,1\right)$.
3. When is $M_f(r)$ constant? I.e., can you classify all functions $f$ for which $M_f(r)$ is constant?
4. Use the fact that $\left|f(z)\right|\leq1-|z|$ to prove that $f$ is constant (using the above steps, of course).

I hope it helps.

Comment: First two hints are clear.. First hint is clear using maximum modulus and second is true because we are increasing the size of the domain and then considering the maximum possible value.. so it increases monotonically... $M_f(r)$ is constant then $M_f(0)=M_f(r)$ for any  $r\in[0,1)$.. So, we have $|f(0)|\geq |f(z)|$ for any $z\in D$.. then $f$ is constant..